# Raspberry pi computer monitor

Tags: sd-card, hdmi

I was told I could use a normal computer monitor with a HDMI, SD card slot, and a couple other nessessary things with any raspberry pi is this true?

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is true. Just need to install an [appropriate OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) on the sd card. Pop it in he board, and you'll see it boot via hdmi.

Answer (score 2):

You can use raspberry pi like normal computer with HDMI or HDMI/VGA conventer cable, sd or microsd card(according to raspberry pi model), and power cable. But, performance of raspberry pi is not enough. I suggest you use raspberry pi Model 2.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try this...what is the preferred raspberry pi for beginners?

Comment: You must know C or Python programming language and linux terminal command for using programming.

Comment: I will learn as I go. I would like to get one to practice and learn

Comment: just get a pi2, it's the most powerful and the price difference won't cripple your budget.

Comment: @kebuter - C or Python is not *essential* - it just helps! Raspian (*other Linux based distributions are available!*) like other [F.O.S.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) Operating Systems at least offers you a range of tools (Compilers/Interpreters/Debuggers and the like) at a price (nothing) that you will like, unlike proprietary Systems where you have to pay to get the powerful, full versions of such things... 8-)